# IReport and getter between classes

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, ireport

I'm using IReport (JasperStudio plugin for Eclipse) and I'm trying to create a report with a JavaBean as source.

Suppose I have these two classes:

```
        public class MyClass {

        private String myClassAttribute;

        // getter and setter for myClassAttribute 
}

        public class AnotherMyClass {

        private String anotherMyClassAttribute;

        private MyClass myClass;

        // getter and setter for anotherMyClassAttribute

     // getter and setter for myClass
    }
```

If I choose AnotherMyClass as JavaBeanSource I can set only fields from that class (**anotherMyClassAttribute**), I didn't find a way to set a text to **getMyClass().getmyClassAttribute()**.

Do JavaBeans stop at level one or is there a way to use attribute from other classes between references?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In report define field $F{myClass} with type MyClass

In text field use expression $F{myClass}.get**M**yClassAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't stop at level one, you may go as deep as you want. You may use the attribute like `myClass.myClassAttribute`. And for setting a value to it, `myClass.myClassAttribute = "some value"`